# How to know if a timeout is due to an element that does not appear or a 400..500 error page

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

During execution of a test suite using Watir and the page-object-gem, we can face Timeout errors. These timeout errors can be caused by:

- a page that, once loaded successfully, does not have the element we are looking for due to a software bug.
- a page that returns a 400 or 500 error code. In this case, obviously outthe element does not appear and the output is the same than before, a timeout error.

What i need to know is if the timeout is because the element does not appear in a correct loaded page or because we get a 400 or 500 error code and, of course, the element is not found.

It seems that the only one logic solution could be to create a custom wait function that checks if the Net::HTTP status code is in between **200..399**, going ahead with execution and continuing with the page-object-gem wait_until or if the status code is in between **400..599**, raising an error page exception.

The question is: **is there any hook or wait method that takes care of the page status code?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will set the default wait time for each page. PageObject.default_page_wait = 60 [It should set in env.rb itself]. else you can use around hook and put your dynamic wait condition there.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an existing hook that does it for you, but page objects have hooks you can use to meet that end.

- initialize_accessors (happens before navigating to the page)
- initialize_page (happens after navigating to the page)

In other words, you could define the initialize_page method, which gets called after navigation to the page, and have it check the page for an error and fail fast if it finds one.